# How do we specify the signal frequency while interfacing DAC 0800 with 8086?

Tags: signal, microprocessor, assembly, 8085

I am relatively new to Microprocessors and just started with my uni course on the same. My faculty while discussing the question:

[image]

gave us the following solution:

[image]

What I don't understand here is how he chose the value of FFh to get the required wave frequency of 500Hz. I get it has something to do with the 8086 frequency and the time it takes to run the loop once. But what is the relation exactly? How did the author and my faculty arrive at the value of FFh to get the required frequency?

Comment: 0xFF is the maximum amplitude of the triangular wave. The frequency depends on the CPU clock, divided by the number of instructions per loop iteration.

Comment: Can you derive that calculation here? So the CPU executes 8*10^6 instructions per second. The loop contains 4 instructions. So the loop should run for 2000 times no?. To get the positive edge for 1 ms, we run the loop 2000 times no because the signal frequency is 2ms? @LiorBilia

Comment: The frequency comes out of trimming how many clock cycles each loop takes (or triggering the loop off a separate clock, if you're so lucky).  That code will make a triangle wave as fast as the processor can go -- normally you'd have to slow it down with NOP instructions or delay loops to get just the right frequency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values 00h and 255 are chosen because the ramp is made to go from 0 to 255 and back to 0. The values are output as fast as possible in a loop.

The CPU just has a clock of 8 MHz, it does not execute 8 million instructions per second, because most instructions take more than 1 clock cycle to execute. The actual cycles how much each CPU instruction takes are found in the CPU manuals.

- OUT immed8, accumulator = 10 cycles
- INC reg8 = 3 cycles
- CMP reg, immed = 4 cycles
- JB = 16 cycles if jump taken, 4 cycles if jump not taken

So each loop takes 33 clock cycles.

Which means that the DAC output updates at a rate of 8 MHz / 33 = 242 kHz, which means that a cycle of triangle wave takes 512 updates so the resulting triangle wave frequency is about 473 Hz - close enough to 500 Hz.

Comment: really helpful. thanks for the insight related to how instructions take multiple clock cycles. Thanks